# error angular.js?body=1:12809 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':

Tags: angularjs

Saludos:

Estoy tratando de enviar la siguiente clase : ng-class = "carta:carta.mostrar" pero me sale el siguiente error de angular:
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [carta:carta.mostrar] .

a que se debe este error ??.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que colores en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: Para que pusiste los 2 puntos?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que quitar los dos puntos

> :

`ng-class = "carta.carta.mostrar"`

o
`ng-class = "carta.mostrar"`

El error en inglés simplemente te está diciendo que hay un erro de sintaxis al encontrar el token  ":" en un lugar donde no esperaba.

> Syntax Error: Token ':is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [carta:carta.mostrar] .

No se cuál será tu caso. En cualquier caso la pregunta está un poco mal formulada. Intenta poner código y demás para que veamos que intentas hacer.